# What might be causing my video card to do this?

Tags: drivers, computer-building

A picture is worth a thousand words. This happened about 3 weeks ago and I have tried updating the BIOS, Drivers, ect.. 3DMark video playback was just as bad. Would a failing or under powered Power supply cause this? Whats also weird is that when using a browser, the display is horrible, yet if I open a program it seems tolerable.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you,
Stephen

[image: Monitors]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the latest drivers from AMD, one possibility is bad memory on the VGA. Use [Graphic Memory Stress Test](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=programs/vmt_en)

Comment: I ran the latest version of BurnInTest for 1/2 hr and not one failure.

Comment: You are welcome! If you like it, vote it up please.

Comment: Also note that if ypu are on Windows, the stock drivers (not downloaded from AMD) can be pretty unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Wife's laptop looked kind of like this when her graphics went out.  Solder joints were breaking on BGA on graphics chip.  [Wikipedia  BGA Page Here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array)

Answer (score 0):

As well as the two answers:

Yes, and bad or underpowered power supply can cause this.

I also would check:

- The cable between the monitor and the computer, (if you are using either a VGA or DVI cable).
  Sometimes a pin can bend, or somehow get pushed back into the plug and cause a back connection which can give you this kind of thing
- Also, your system info don't show this, what is the temperature like (reading from bios or what it feels like to your hand)
  You could try putting a fan on it to see if it gets better?
- It indicates you have 2 monitors. Have you tried just one connected?

Answer (score 0):

1. As Zathraszero suggest, try to test cables.
2. Is the resolution displayed much lower than the LCD Native? Can't be certain from pics...
3. Does it displays on one LCD only?
4. What are the reading from Temperature tab? Is there anything usable?

Depending on the answers above it may be cable or graphics chip dying (yes to 2 & 3). Unfortunately. You're running an APU, which mean CPU and GPU are on the same die, so I would rule out lack of power - APU uses WAAAAY LESS power than rig with extra VGA card.